# Buscar dos registros al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo un buscador para mi pagina web, quiero realizar algo como un "Filtro de búsqueda", al querer buscar el genero y nombre de un libro a la vez, no me sale ningún registro, pero si busco solo el nombre o el genero si me trae los registros con dicho valor. Esta es la parte de la consulta que tiene la función de buscar en la tabla de la base de datos.

```
$categoria = $_REQUEST['categoria'] ;
$busqueda = strtolower ($_REQUEST['busqueda']);
$buscar = $categoria.$busqueda;
?>


  <?php
// incluimos la conexión 
require_once("../conexionbd/conexion.php");

// consultar la tabla productos
$sql_registe = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registro FROM producto
INNER JOIN categoria ON producto.Categoria_IDCategoria = categoria.IDCategoria
INNER JOIN estado ON producto.Estado_IDEstado = estado.IDEstado 
INNER JOIN editorial ON producto.Editorial_IDEditorial = Editorial.IDEditorial 
INNER JOIN estante ON producto.Estante_IDEstante = Estante.IDEstante
INNER JOIN autor ON producto.Autor_IDAutor = autor.IDAutor WHERE (IDProducto LIKE '%$buscar%' OR NombreProducto LIKE '%$buscar%' OR
Portada LIKE '%$buscar%' OR CantidadEjemplares LIKE '%$buscar%' OR categoria.NombreCategoria LIKE '%$buscar%' OR
estado.Estado LIKE '%$buscar%' OR editorial.NombreEditorial LIKE '%$buscar%' OR estante.Estante LIKE '%$buscar%' OR
autor.NombreAutor LIKE '%$buscar%' )");
```

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: No entiendo como esta consulta no da error, ya que la sintaxis correcta debería ser algo como `IDProducto LIKE '%".$categoria.$busqueda."%'` (_te están sobrando comillas en todas las condiciones_)

Comment: Siento que el error está en que el valor viene en un solo variable .$categoria.$busqueda. En esta variable estas enviando el nombre y el genero? de ser asi por eso no te trae información, ahora bien OR se usa cuando, si no encuentras registros con un valor o por un campo se vaya a la otra condición y no funcionará enviando 2 valores, o es una o es otra. Lo que yo haria sería identificar cuando viajen los 2 opciones  (nombre y genero) entonces mandaría la sentencia AND.

Comment: Has cambiado la pregunta de tal manera que has dejado mi respuesta totalmente inválida!

Answer (score 0):

Me sorprende que la consulta publicada no genere error en la base de datos, pero mySQL es conocido por *aceptar* cosas que no debiera, con resultados impredecibles.

Si realizamos mentalmente la sustitución, suponiendo que `$categoria` vale `'A'` y $busqueda tiene el valor de `'B'`, la sustitución quedaría así:

```sql
WHERE (
   IDProducto LIKE '%' 'AB' '%'
   OR NombreProducto LIKE '%' 'AB' '%'
   OR Portada LIKE '%' 'AB' '%'
   OR CantidadEjemplares LIKE '%' 'AB' '%' 
   OR categoria.NombreCategoria LIKE '%' 'AB' '%' 
   OR estado.Estado LIKE '%' 'AB' '%' 
   OR editorial.NombreEditorial LIKE '%' 'AB' '%' 
   OR estante.Estante LIKE '%' 'AB' '%' 
   OR autor.NombreAutor LIKE '%' 'AB' '%'
)
```

Es **evidente** que la sintaxis es inválida para SQL.

Por lo mismo, es buena idea *imprimir* el texto de las consultas en la propia página, o almacenarlo en un archivo de texto, para poder *inspeccionar* que la programación esté produciendo el resultado que teníamos en mente al escribir el script.

Yo muchas veces he hecho esto, de manera rápida (y sucia) para ver el texto de una consulta mientras la *afino* o depuro.

```php
$sql = "bla, bla, bla, bla".$var=1?"esto":"aquello"."bla bla bla";
die($sql);
```

Dicho esto, además:

- No entiendo por qué estás concatenando dos variables par construir la condición de búsqueda en cada campo, podrías tener toda la condición en una sola variable y usar esa, lo que simplificará el código
- Tu consulta puede ser vulnerable a [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Lo recomendable, para evitar esta vulnerabilidad, es el uso de consultas parametrizadas. Lo menciono, porque es **muy importante** pero no haré cambios a tu código en esa línea.
- Simplificaré las cosas:

  - Declarando una única variable que tenga toda la cadena a buscar
  - Valiéndome de la evaluación de variables que hace *php* de manera automática dentro de strings delimitados por comillas dobles, así evitamos *complicar* el código con concatenaciones, al ser más simple es más fácil de escribir y de mantener.

```php
$cadenaBuscar = $categoria.$busqueda;
$sqlWhere = " 
 WHERE IDProducto LIKE '%$cadenaBuscar%'
    OR NombreProducto LIKE '%$cadenaBuscar%'
    OR Portada LIKE '%$cadenaBuscar%'
    OR CantidadEjemplares LIKE '%$cadenaBuscar%'
    OR categoria.NombreCategoria LIKE '%$cadenaBuscar%'
    OR estado.Estado LIKE '%$cadenaBuscar%'
    OR editorial.NombreEditorial LIKE '%$cadenaBuscar%'
    OR estante.Estante LIKE '%$cadenaBuscar%'
    OR autor.NombreAutor LIKE '%$cadenaBuscar%'
";
```

Creo que ahora, al tener código más simple, no solo se ve claramente cuál es la intención original, sino que es más fácil detectar algún error en la sentencia con una simple inspección.

Volviendo al ejemplo de los valores `'A'` y `'B'` en las variables originales, ahora las condiciones van a quedar asi:

```sql
WHERE IDProducto LIKE '%AB%'
   OR NombreProducto LIKE '%AB%'
   OR Portada LIKE '%AB%'
   OR CantidadEjemplares LIKE '%AB%'
   OR categoria.NombreCategoria LIKE '%AB%'
   OR estado.Estado LIKE '%AB%'
   OR editorial.NombreEditorial LIKE '%AB%'
   OR estante.Estante LIKE '%AB%'
   OR autor.NombreAutor LIKE '%AB%'
```

Diría que es lo que buscas.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, probé los dos métodos que propusiste pero me sigue sin traer registros, solo funciona si busco el uno o el otro (Categoría o Nombre), agradecería tu ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si _pruebas_ mi código, sin esforzarte por leer y comprender mi explicación, claro que va a pasar que no funcione.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está aquí: `$buscar = $categoria.$busqueda;`

No deberías concatenar, sino usar los filtros por separado:

```
$sql_registe = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registro FROM producto
INNER JOIN categoria ON producto.Categoria_IDCategoria = categoria.IDCategoria
INNER JOIN estado ON producto.Estado_IDEstado = estado.IDEstado 
INNER JOIN editorial ON producto.Editorial_IDEditorial = Editorial.IDEditorial 
INNER JOIN estante ON producto.Estante_IDEstante = Estante.IDEstante
INNER JOIN autor ON producto.Autor_IDAutor = autor.IDAutor 
WHERE (   IDProducto LIKE '%$busqueda%' 
       OR NombreProducto LIKE '%$busqueda%' 
       OR Portada LIKE '%$busqueda%' 
       OR CantidadEjemplares LIKE '%$busqueda%' 
       OR categoria.NombreCategoria LIKE '%$categoria%' 
       OR estado.Estado LIKE '%$busqueda%' 
       OR editorial.NombreEditorial LIKE '%$busqueda%' 
       OR estante.Estante LIKE '%$busqueda%' 
       OR autor.NombreAutor LIKE '%$busqueda%' 
      )");
```